# General Term for Offsets Plural

Tags: irregular-plurals

Is there a general term for multi-word entities where the pluralization appears on the first word because the following words are adjectival (but required) modifiers?

#### Examples

- Attorney General `->` Attorneys General
- Medal of Honor `->` Medals of Honor
- Runner-up `->` Runners-up

#### Bonus Question

Is there a term to describe jovial deliberate misuse of this property? Either by improper reordering of the usual adjective-noun pair (*"phones mobile"*) or by keeping the usual ordering and applying the formal rule even though it does not apply (*"mobiles phone"*).

Comment: Also, knights errant....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no special term for such nouns other than [*noun phrases with postpositive adjective*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postpositive_adjective), a rather limited set which includes a number of non-count nouns (malice aforethought) and others where a plural would be automatic (women alone). Many of these nouns are legal terms inherited from French and Latin or fully English expressions like *Princess Royal* that nevertheless follow Romance syntax with the adjective usually following the noun.

Since in the entire history of the British monarchy there have only been seven [princesses royal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princess_Royal), including the current holder of the title, Princess Anne, it’s not a word whose plural is required very often except in statements like this one. The French word order is the work of the one who insisted the Crown create such a title for the eldest daughter of a reigning monarch, the French queen of Charles I, [Henrietta Maria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henrietta_Maria_of_France). All of the “generals” — attorney, consul, governor, paymaster, surgeon, vicar — form plurals in the same way.

Now when this French syntax meets the Saxon genitive, it’s a grammatical Waterloo: only [two US Supreme Court decisions](http://joshblackman.com/blog/2013/02/18/why-is-it-attorneys-general-plural-but-not-attorneys-general-singular-possessive/) have ever used the form *attorney’s general*; the rest have resorted to *attorney general’s* or to what Fowler called the “Norman” genitive: *of the attorney general*.

> The [Attorney General's Office](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/attorney-generals-office) (AGO) provides legal advice and support to the Attorney General and the Solicitor General (the Law Officers) who give legal advice to government. — Attorney General's Office - GOV.UK

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/attorney%20general) does allow *attorney generals* as a plural, but there is considerable [resistance](http://www.lawprose.org/lawprose-lesson-262-plural-attorney-general/) among the legal profession to the change.

To complicate matters, French and Latin noun phrases generally form their plurals as they do in those languages:

persona non grata     personae non gratae

agent provacateur     agents provacateurs

agente provacatrice  agentes provacatrices

cause célèbre             causes célèbres

femme fatal                femmes fatales

A retired professor can also sport a gendered adjective: professor emertus, professor emerita, and if there's more than one, professors emeriti, professors emeritae.

As for what to call something like **phones mobile* — why not completely cross the Channel with **phones mobiles*? — I’d call that a humorous pseudoforeignism, like pronouncing the big box store Target as if it were the French name of some upscale shop.

Answer (score -3):

Attorney General and Medal of Honour are items that by the nature of their significance convey singularity. The condition of being singular is to be maintained. E.G.: The Attonery General of the member states; The Medal of Honor for the laureats of this year are in my closet.

Comment: Do you mean I can't say "the Attorneys General of Maryland and Massachusetts"? What if they have a meeting? Would I have to say "the Attorney General met" and not "the Attorneys General met"?

Comment: Convention for both of these is to pluralize as indicated in the question ([MOH](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/Medal%20of%20Honor), [AG](http://joshblackman.com/blog/2013/02/18/why-is-it-attorneys-general-plural-but-not-attorneys-general-singular-possessive/)).

Comment: I approached the question from the connotion of the word meaning. But  it is indeed grammatically correct to pluralize as indicated.